# Javascript array of objects check for key

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

[image]

So my question how can I check this array of objects by "key" for eg I want to check if the key `3892` is there, I have tried with `indexOf` but no luck, I can't use a loop.

Comment: you need to call `Object.keys(yourJSONObject)` first to get array of key and search in that array https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `some()` and `hasOwnProperty()`

```js
var array = [{3892: 'value'}, {1234: 'value'}];

var check = array.some(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(3892));
console.log(check)
```

Comment: Do you also now how can I get the value based on this? because this returns true which is good but I also need the value

Comment: Do you mean value as object?

Comment: Well let's say in this case for 3892 I need the value.. in this case 'value'

Comment: You can return object using `find` and then check if object is returned and access value https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1774/

Answer (score 2):

You can chain [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to achieve that

```
Object.keys(myObject).includes(myKey);
```

---

```js
const myObject = { name: 'Peter' };
const myKey = 'name';

const result = Object.keys(myObject).includes(myKey);

console.log(`Includes key ${myKey}? `,  result);
```